# How to change the code to paste formula in every column every 7th row?

Tags: excel, vba

I created the below code so it can paste the formula every 7th row in column AK until the last empty cell in column D and it is working as expected, however, I need to perform the same action but for next 30 columns to the right(from AK to BO).

Can you please guide how I can change this code? Also, I think something is wrong with the code line defining LastRow: `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row`. It is working but it sometimes it is pasting some weird result to the last row in column AJ

Every guide is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Worksheets("Data")

    With sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 8 To LastRow Step 7

       .Cells(r, "AK").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(R[4]C[-32]="""",R[5]C[-32]=""""),R7C[-32]&"","","""")"

    Next
    End With
```

Comment: you will want another loop nesting the current one.  This will loop the columns.

Comment: In addition to what Scott said, you should use column numbers, not letters so that it's easier for you to loop through them.

Comment: And....try to avoid select, it's unnecessary :)

Comment: @ScottCraner you don't have to do the other loop; you could do `ActiveCell.Resize(0,31).Formula =  `

Comment: @GMalc yes.....yes you can.  I did not flip my perspective.  Good catch.

Comment: @GMalc but you do not need the `.Offset()` it does nothing.

Comment: @ScottCraner so happy i caught something forgot to remove offset

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input, very much appreciated. Error 1004 amended the formula and is spot on now! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not pretty sure if a get the point but you can modify the below code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

  Dim Row As Long, Column As Long, LastRow As Long

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        For Row = 8 To LastRow Step 7

            For Column = 37 To 67 Step 30

                .Cells(Row, Column).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(R[4]C[-32]="""",R[5]C[-32]=""""),R7C[-32]&"","","""")"

            Next Column

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. now I know how to next 2x for in once. I had to delete ""Step 30" from Column = 37 To 67 Step 30 and it worked as intended! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: if the answer is what you are looking for vote it to helps others.